# Baking using Collection Instances (or Object face duplication) does not work

Tags: texture-baking, instances, collections

I'm setting up a 'Tiled texture studio', to do so I have set up a collection at 0,0,0 with numerous objects. I then create Collection instances at equal x and y offsets around the tile area. When I try to bake I get the error:

Object "TileObjects" is not a mesh or can't be converted to a mesh (Curve, Text, Surface or Metaball)

If i try a similar approach where I create a 1 time subdivided plane, link the original objects in the TileObjects collection to it, and then set the duplication mode of the subdivided plane to 'Faces', it perfectly makes the desired tiling, but the only mesh calculated for the bake are the original objects in the TileObjects Collection, none of the other instances are calculated in the bake.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

[image]